# Multiplying two matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two matrix in c++ but result not correct! 
Could you please let me know what's wrong with ,my code?!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
//more detail
using namespace std;
#define WIDTH1 3
#define HEIGHT1 3
#define WIDTH2 3
#define HEIGHT2 3
#define WIDTH3 3
#define HEIGHT3 3
int A[HEIGHT1][WIDTH1];
int B[HEIGHT2][WIDTH2];
int C[HEIGHT3][WIDTH3];
int n, m;
int y = 0;
//more detail :)

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cin >> m;
            A[i][j] = m;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cin >> n;
            B[i][j] = n;
        }
//more detail :)

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        int k = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        int sum3 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            int sum = A[i][j] * B[j][i];
            sum += sum; 
        }
        B[i][y] = sum;
        y = y + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            int sum2 = A[i][j] * B[j][i];
            sum2 += sum2;
        }
        B[i][y] = sum2;
        y = y + 1;
//more detail :)

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            int sum3 = A[i][j] * B[j][i];
            sum3 += sum3;
        }
        B[i][y] = sum3;
        y = y + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            cout << B[i][j] <<"\t" << B[i][j+1] << "\t" << B[i][j+2] << "\n" ;
        }
    return 0;
//more detail :)

}
```

Comment: Downvoted because of "_more detail :)_" spam. If the system notifies you to add more detail to your question, consider doing so. For instance: you state "_but result not correct!_", but don't provide the input used, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: I recommend learning to use the gdb debugger, step through line by line and check what numbersa are being recorded. I'm sure you will crack it in no time!

Comment: Don't circumvent adding ***actual*** problem details by filling your post with junk.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there are some other issues than the variable shadowings. [test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fLu4fnb1MmPLEcSE)

Comment: Hmmm. the algorithm is wrong.

Comment: MikeCAT Yes I just change algorithm  https://wandbox.org/permlink/qnuSzaRQxhX8BYe0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think this does:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int sum = A[i][j] * B[j][i];
        sum += sum; 
    }
```

in relation with your original `sum`? It doesn't do anything.

Don't redeclare the same variable.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sum += A[i][j] * B[j][i];
    }
```

Comment: Stating that something should be obvious doesn't add to the answer and can be disrespectful to the person you are addressing. The existence of the question shows that was evidently not obvious enough and implying that it should have been can feel like a critical comment on the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I just change it and now it's clearly work
It was base to try to remember basic things that I knew and start to learn C++ again!!
here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
#define WIDTH1 3
#define HEIGHT1 3
#define WIDTH2 3
#define HEIGHT2 3
#define WIDTH3 3
#define HEIGHT3 3
int A[HEIGHT1][WIDTH1];
int B[HEIGHT2][WIDTH2];
int C[HEIGHT3][WIDTH3];
int n, m, sum;
int y = 0;
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cin >> m;
            A[i][j] = m;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cin >> n;
            B[i][j] = n;
        }
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                sum = sum + A[c][k] * B[k][d];
            }

            C[c][d] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            cout << C[i][j] <<"\t" << C[i][j+1] << "\t" << C[i][j+2] << "\n" ;
        }
    return 0;
}
```